# Check if variable is defined in the superclass or subclass

Tags: python, inheritance

This is just academic. Consider the following example:

```
class Shape():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def position(self):
        return self.x, self.y


class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        #super().__init__(x, y)  # OK
        self.x = x  # not OK!
        self.y = y  # not OK!
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

r1 = Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

If I asked someone to implement the class Rectangle, and they implemented with the "not OK" statements (instead of the with the "OK" statement as they should), then `r1.x` would be an attribute of `Rectangle` instead of `Shape`. Is there a way I can check if `r1.x` is a member of the Rectangle class or of the Shape class? Essentially, I want to make sure the initialization of the super class is being run, and no unnecessary new attributes are being created.

Comment: It's not part of either class, in either way you suggest. You can properly declare it as attribute/property in the base class though, that would make it clearer. Also, you can use one or two underscores in front.

Comment: It doesn't matter how `r1.x` et al. are set as long as the *result* is correct.

Comment: Even if you call `super`, `x` and `y` are still "Rectangle" attributes, in the sense that `self` has type `Rectangle` when `Shape.__init__` gets called. You are ascribing C++-style class semantics where they do not apply.